# How can I clear only one specific form field after submit?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm creating a chat application and there are 2 fields, receiver's name and body, 
I would like to clear the body which is the `comment` field without clearing the receiver's name after form submit, how can I achieve that ?

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = userCommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(client=request.user)
        > clear comment field.
```

**forms.py** ("worker" field is the receiver's name.)

```
class userCommentForm(forms.Form):
    worker = CommaSeparatedUserField(label=_(u"worker"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))
    comment = forms.CharField(label=_(u"comment"), widget=forms.Textarea())

    def save(self, client):
        workers = self.cleaned_data['worker']
        comment = self.cleaned_data['comment']
        message_list = []
        for worker in workers:
            msg = userComment(client=client, worker=worker, comment=comment,)

            if None is not None:
                msg.parent_msg = None
                None.save()
            msg.save()
            message_list.append(msg)

        return message_list
        form.save(client=request.user)
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What do you mean `clear body field`?

Comment: Once the form is submited, `comment` field should be cleared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some misunderstanding here. After a form is submitted and processed in a web application, you shouldn't continue with anything for current request anymore, but you should send `GET` request to another web page. Thus, it's not possible to set a form field as empty after submission.

What I suggest is that when your form is submitted, you redirect to the same page but with a `GET` parameter storing what name was submitted, then in the beginning of the view you feed the form with the name as initial parameter:

```
def view_method(request):
    default_receiver = request.GET.get('receiver', None)
    form = userCommentForm(request.POST or None,
                           request.FILES or None,
                           initial={'worker': default_receiver})
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(client=request.user)
        current_receiver = form.cleaned_data['worker']
        response = redirect('current-page-url-name')
        response['Location'] += '?receiver=%s' % current_receiver
        return response
```

Comment: Hmm that's what I thought too, I wanted to check if it was possible, since later on I would like to add ajax, so the form doesn't redirect each time and the `comment` field get's reset.

Comment: Then send the data use ajax, upon its return use javascript to clean the comment.